# Why java script fs.readFileSync is not getting mocked?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

i have a fs.readFileSync function that i need to mock using jest.
i have tried the below code.

my original file which i want to test.

```
   const fs = require('fs');


const read_file = (path) => {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error in read_file', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const getSecret = secretName => {
  try {
    return read_file(`/etc/secrets/${secretName}.txt`);
  } catch (err){
    throw err;
  }
};

const secretConfig = {
  kafka_keystore_password: getSecret('kafka_keystore_password')
};

module.exports = secretConfig;
```

here is my test case

```
const secret = require('./secret');
let fs = require('fs')
jest.mock('fs');






describe('secret read files', () => {
    afterEach(jest.restoreAllMocks);
  it('should read secret from file', () => {
    //fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue("randomPrivateKey");  
    fs.readFileSync.mockResolvedValue("randomPrivateKey")
    const secretMessage = secret.kafka_keystore_password;
    //expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');

  })

})

describe('getSecretsFromFile', () => {
    const secret = 'secret';
    const secrets = { mySecret: secret };
  
    afterEach(jest.restoreAllMocks);
  
    it('returns secrets if file is present', () => {
      fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(true);
      fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue('randomPrivateKey');
  
      const secretMessage = secret.kafka_keystore_password;
      expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
    });
});
```

and i get the following error.

> FAIL  src/config/secret.test.js   ● secret read files › should read
> secret from file
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "randomPrivateKey"
> Received: undefined
>
>   15 |     const secretMessage = secret.kafka_keystore_password;
>   16 |     //expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
> > 17 |     expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
>      |                           ^
>   18 |
>   19 |   })
>   20 |
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/config/secret.test.js:17:27)
> ```
>
> ● getSecretsFromFile › returns secrets if file is present
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "randomPrivateKey"
> Received: undefined
>
>   32 |   
>   33 |       const secretMessage = secret.kafka_keystore_password;
> > 34 |       expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
>      |                             ^
>   35 |     });
>   36 | });
>   37 |     
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/config/secret.test.js:34:29)
> ```

help me fix this .

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem please add a comment below it. If it does then please accept my answer. Happy to help but I might require further information.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
const fs = {
readFileSync: jest.fn(() => ({ message: 'Test'}))
}
```

to mock the fs readFileSync message.

But I don't see how this test is ever going to pass because you're returning value "Test"

but checking for `randomPrivateKey`

```
expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
```

Without seeing what's going on inside the code it's difficult to say but I am assuming you might want to change that line to:

```
expect(secretMessage).toEqual('test');
```

As `test` is the value your mocking alternatively return `randomPrivateKey` from the mock.

I'm having to make a load of assumptions here because I don't know-how
`secret.kafka_keystore_password` is calculated. I'm assuming it just returns the whatever the `fs.readFileSync` returns.7

Comment: added more details about my original file, also i have fixed my testing condition . now even after trying your suggestion i am getting "Expected: "randomPrivateKey"
    Received: undefined" error

Comment: but it looks like you're still using? fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue('randomPrivateKey');
If you haven't done so can you please update ALL of the code examples to reflect your implementation of my suggestion?

Comment: why is that a problem i am expecting what i mocked only ?

Comment: look at my answer again and see how I am mocking using jest.fn(()=>{}) it's how I use jest and it works for me.

Comment: can you post full code to get accepted answer, its not working for me.